# May Make $\frac5{2020}$ 2020

Tags: lateral-thinking, formation-of-numbers, optimization

For May 2020, try to create $\dfrac{5}{2020}$ using **the least** possible number of integers in the set $\{1,3,4,6,7,8,9\}$.

$2$, $5$ and $0$ are not allowed.

Example:

$$\dfrac{4+1}{3\left(673+\frac13\right)}$$

Uses $1,1,3,3,3,4,6$ and $7$ $\implies$ $8$ numbers. You must do better than $7$ numbers.

You are allowed to use any operation as long as you can find a wikipedia page created before 2020, that's why there is a lateral thinking tag.

**Improving puzzle - thanks to @athin's answer and @Daniel Mathias' comments**
Any mathematical constant apart from $\{1,3,4,6,7,8,9\}$ is **not** allowed!

$$\dfrac{\lfloor \phi \rfloor}{\lceil e^{\lfloor \pi + \pi\rfloor}\rceil} $$

is equal to $\frac{5}{2020}$ but it's not a valid solution!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the good ol' functions like:

> ceiling and [exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) functions.

Here is a way with only just **two** digits!

> $$\frac{1}{\lceil \exp(6) \rceil} = \frac{1}{404} = \frac{5}{2020}$$

Comment: Might as well use $\lfloor\pi+\pi\rfloor$...

Comment: I'm not sure if using constant is allowed, as we can just have five $\pi$s divided by two thousand twenty $\pi$s.

Comment: 5 $\pi$s divided by 2020 $\pi$s is not equal to $5$ divided by $2020$ but the spirit of your comment is true! I'm editing my question accordingly to your answer and remark!

Comment: @JKHA huh? 5 s divided by 2020 s by definition is equal to 5/2020.

Comment: @Quintec oh yeah, I should go to sleep, I was thinking of $\pi^5$, forget about that x)

Comment: This is very nice. +1

Answer (score 13):

Here is a way to do it with four digits

> $$\frac{5}{2020} = \frac{1}{8!! + 4! - 4} $$ where we have used [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)

Here is a way to do it with three digits

> $$ \frac{5}{2020} = \frac{1}{8!! + \sigma(\sigma(8))} $$ where $\sigma$ is the [Divisor sum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_divisors)

Answer (score 8):

Improved solution:

> See [Home prime](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_prime).
>  $\frac{1}{93+HP(9)}=\frac{1}{93+311}=\frac{1}{404}=\frac{5}{2020}$

Straightforward solution:

> Using five digits, $\frac{4}{1616}=\frac{5}{2020}$

Comment: Nice ;) Straightforward and optimal?

Comment: @JKHA Likely optimal. Though I wouldn't call it yet. Could be a creative solution with fewer digits.

Comment: I was asking you knowing there is better ;)

Comment: @JKHA See improved solution.

Comment: By the way, I like your straightforward solution a lot for its simplicity!

Answer (score 3):

Using

> [string concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) (here denoted by $\otimes$, e.g. $2\otimes5=25$), Wikipedia page about it was created in 2002 and even last modified in 2019

we can get

> $$\frac1{4\otimes(6-6) \otimes 4}=\frac1{404}=\frac5{2020}$$.

Comment: I believe the actual symbol is $||$ (ex. $2||(3+4)=27$).

Answer (score 2):

This uses four digits as well:

> $$\frac{1}{4 \cdot p(13)}$$

where

> $p(n)$ is the number of distinct integer [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$.